# pythonにおける任意のネスト数のループ処理について

Tags: python, numpy

以下のような関数を作成したいと思っているのですが、任意の回数ループ処理を行う方法についてご教示賜りたいと存じます。

１．引数として、①任意の次元数のnumpy配列、②各次元に対応する処理を行う関数の２つをとる。
②すべての配列要素に対して処理を行う。ただし、その処理は引数として指定した関数に基づく。

この時、任意の回数のネストした処理の作成方法がわかりません。
例えば4次元配列なら、汚いですが

```py
x = NDARRAY.shape
for i in range(x[0]):
    for j in range(x[1]):
        for k in range(x[2]):
            for l in range(x[3]):
```

とでもできますが、一般にn次元の時、どのようにすればよいでしょうか。
メタプログラミングの知識は必要でしょうか。

Comment: 質問の例の場合、最奥のループ内(`for l in range(x[3]):`)では、`i`,`j`,`k`,`l`を使った処理を行うイメージでしょうか?

Comment: ご理解のとおりです。最奥部においてもすべてのインデックスを用いたいと考えています

Answer (score 3):

任意の深さのネストを再帰で表現した実装例です。
**【実装例】**

```py
import numpy as np
def looploop(func, na, dims=None, indexes=[], level=0, no=0, first=True):
    if dims is None:
        dims = na.shape
    if first:
        indexes = [0] * len(dims)
    if len(dims) <= 0:
        func(na, indexes)
        return
    for i in range(dims[0]):
        indexes[level] = i
        looploop(func, na, dims[1:], indexes=indexes, level=level+1, no=i, first=False)

def func1(na, indexes):
    print("Hello:indexes=" + str(indexes))

na = np.ndarray((2,3,4,5))

looploop(func1, na)
```

- 処理名
  looploop
- ①任意の次元数のnumpy配列
  na
- ②各次元に対応する処理を行う関数
  func
- funcの第１引数(numpy配列)
  na
- funcの第２引数(インデックス)
  indexes

**【注意】**
KLCさんの回答にある、多次元配列のデータを**１次元配列で管理した方が速度面で有利**だと思います。

【多次元】

```
サイズ　     tttt[SIZE_1][SIZE_2][SIZE_3][SIZE_4]
インデックス tttt[i1][i2][i3][i4]
```

【１次元】

```
サイズ　     t[SIZE_1 * SIZE_2 * SIZE_3 * SIZE_4]
インデックス t[i]
i = i1 * SIZE_2 * SIZE_3 * SIZE_4
  + i2 * SIZE_3 * SIZE_4
  + i3 * SIZE_4
  + i4
```

iから各インデックスを求める場合は以下の式で計算します。

```
    i1 = (i % (SIZE_1 * SIZE_2 * SIZE_3 * SIZE_4)) // (SIZE_2 * SIZE_3 * SIZE_4)
    i2 = (i % (SIZE_2 * SIZE_3 * SIZE_4)) // (SIZE_3 * SIZE_4)
    i3 = (i % (SIZE_3 * SIZE_4)) // (SIZE_4)
    i4 = (i % SIZE_4)
```

Answer (score 2):

nditerをmulti_indexフラグ付きで使うといいですね。
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html

```py
import numpy as np

x  = np.random.randn(2, 3)

it = np.nditer(x, flags=['multi_index'])

while not it.finished:
    # x と it.multi_index を使って何かをする
    print(it.multi_index)
    print(x[it.multi_index])

    # 次に進める
    it.iternext()
```

```
(0, 0)
0.23465161779473015
(0, 1)
0.22383801010291296
(0, 2)
-0.8051323435933129
(1, 0)
0.8931324229893808
(1, 1)
-0.4271553422304515
(1, 2)
-2.146703943718106
```

```py
# 次元が違うデータ
x  = np.random.randn(2, 3, 2)

# 以下のコードはまったく同じ
it = np.nditer(x, flags=['multi_index'])

while not it.finished:
    print(it.multi_index)
    print(x[it.multi_index])
    it.iternext()
```

```
(0, 0, 0)
0.30500812464361104
(0, 0, 1)
0.7671660280535492
(0, 1, 0)
-0.87198212525212
(0, 1, 1)
-0.6311542834847657
(0, 2, 0)
0.5198028854150701
(0, 2, 1)
0.8153458301759646
(1, 0, 0)
-0.7942063485178719
(1, 0, 1)
-1.568633897435036
(1, 1, 0)
-1.3299054158710617
(1, 1, 1)
-0.4096393538574391
(1, 2, 0)
-0.03538806394741229
(1, 2, 1)
0.5462354038739015
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。 ndinterにそのような引数があることや、プレースホルダで取得して直積作ることなど、自分ではまったく思いつかないことです。

Answer (score 0):

こんなのはどうでしょうか。アイデアとしては、添え字を生成してから、1段のループですべての要素をスキャンするというような感じです:

```py
import itertools
import numpy as np


# main
def f(A, g):
  for idx in itertools.product(*[range(n) for n in A.shape]):
    g(A, A[idx], *idx)


# callback
def h(Arr, Elm, *idx):
  assert Arr[idx] == Elm
  print('Arr[%s] = %f' % (str(idx), Elm))


# for example...
shape = (2, 3, 4, 5)
X = np.arange(np.product(shape)).reshape(shape)
f(X, h)
```

出力例:

```
Arr[(0, 0, 0, 0)] = 0.000000
Arr[(0, 0, 0, 1)] = 1.000000
Arr[(0, 0, 0, 2)] = 2.000000
Arr[(0, 0, 0, 3)] = 3.000000
Arr[(0, 0, 0, 4)] = 4.000000
...
```